# Duda con css en java

Tags: java, html, css, jsp

tengo este `css` para aplicar estilo a un **topnav**:

﻿

```css
.topnav .login-container {
    float: right;
}

.topnav label{
    padding: 6px;
    margin-top: 8px;
    margin-right: 16px;
    font-size: 17px;
    border: none;
    width: 120px;
    height: 30px;
    color: white;
    float: right;
}

.topnav label {
    padding: 6px;
    margin-top: 8px;
    margin-right: 12px;
    font-size: 15px;
    border: none;
    width: 240px;
    height: 30px;
}

.topnav button {
    float: right;
    padding: 6px 8px;
    margin-top: 8px;
    margin-right: 14px;
    background-color: #f44336;
    color: white;
    font-size: 17px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 30px;
}

.topnav .login-container button:hover {
    background-color: #f44336;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .topnav .login-container {
        float: none;
    }

    .topnav a, .topnav label, .topnav .login-container button {
        float: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 14px;
    }

    .topnav input[type=text] {
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/botones.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/imagen.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/menu.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/login/login.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/login/loginNav.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="topnav">
            <a href="#">Home</a>
            <div class="login-container">
                <button onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" style="width:auto;">Login</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="id01" class="modal">
            <form class="modal-content animate" onsubmit="return control()" method="POST" action="indexLogin">
                <div class="imgcontainer">
                    <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Cerrar modal">&times;</span>
                    <img src="imagenes/00.png" alt="imagen" class="avatar">
                </div>
                <div class="container">
                    <label for="uname"><b>Usuario:</b></label>
                    <input type="text" id="uname" placeholder="Ingrese usuario..." name="uname" onkeypress="return soloLetras(event)"/>
                    
                    <label for="psw"><b>Password:</b></label>
                    <input type="password" id="psw" placeholder="Ingrese contraseña..." name="psw" onkeypress="return soloLetras(event)"/>
                    
                    <button type="submit">Iniciar sesión</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    <center><img class="img" src="imagenes/00.png"/></center>
    <center><p>Bienvenida/a, por favor presione el botón para ver la lista de parejas o de precios.</p></center>
    <center>
        <form method="POST" action="listaParejasSinLogin">
            <button name="btnListaParejas" style="width: 150px">Parejas</button>
            <button name="btnListaPrecios" style="width: 150px">Precios</button>
        </form>
    </center>
    
    <script>
        function control(){
            if(document.getElementById('uname').value == null || 
                    document.getElementById('uname').value == ""){
                alert('El campo no puede estar vacío.');
                document.getElementById('uname').focus();
                return false;
            }
            else if(document.getElementById('psw').value == null || 
                    document.getElementById('psw').value == ""){
                alert('El campo no puede estar vacío');
                document.getElementById('psw').focus();
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Y se ve así en el **index**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero, en la página siguiente se desconfigura:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/botones.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/imagen.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/menu.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/login/login.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/login/loginNav.css">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Lista Parejas</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css"
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="topnav">
            <a href="#">Home</a>
            <div class="login-container">
                <button onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" style="width:auto;">Login</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div class="w3-container">
            <ul class="w3-ul w3-card-4">
                <c:forEach items="${lista}" var="P">
                    <li class="w3-bar">
                        <div class="w3-bar-item">
                            <span class="w3-large">${P.nombreCompleto1} - ${P.nombreCompleto2}</span>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </c:forEach>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quizá es la librería del w3 que te sobrescribe algún estilo.

Prueba a ponerla la primera de todas, al principio del head.

Comment: Por favor lee [answer], esto parece mas un comentario o pregunta que una respuesta en si